# Retrieving Row Data from a Column in DataGrid in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've created a Column button in datagrid using this code

```
<Columns>
    <asp:ButtonColumn Text="Resend" ButtonType="PushButton" CommandName="Resend"></asp:ButtonColumn> </Columns>
```

But I don't know where to access the event of this Button, also I would like to know how to retrive the row data of this button thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using FindControl.

See this example:http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) of how to this
[One more sample](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/70_Useful_GridView_Tips.aspx) with simple code.